# UITableView cell UIImageView changes his frame randomly when selected

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm struggling with the following problem:
I'm downloading a title and an imageUrl from Json and I'm setting them inside my UITableView custom cell with the following method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Retrieve cell
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell *categoryCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    categoryCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    categoryCell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

    // Get the location to be shown
    RecipesList *item = _feedRecipesList[indexPath.row];




    // Get references to labels of cell
    categoryCell.textLabel.text = item.name;
    item.urlImg = [item.urlImg stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"];
    [categoryCell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:item.urlImg]
                placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Placeholder.png"]];



    return categoryCell;
}
```

Everything works fine but when I select a cell (so it gets highlighted) the UIImageView frame of the cell changes it's size for no reasons. At first I was using basic cell and I thought the problem was caused by that so I tried with custom cell and on the custom class I added on the .m file the following code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
[super layoutSubviews];

self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,55,55);

//Any additional setting that you want to do with image view

[self.imageView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingNone];

}
```

It does resize the UIImageView but again if i select a cell the image frame changes.

Does anyone had the same issue?

And also in order to create the lazy loading i'm using the library SDWebImage but I don't think that the problem is related to that.

Answer (score 0):

Strange behavior. Just a few suggestions, try this

```
self.autoresizesSubviews = NO;
self.contentView.clipsToBounds = YES;
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Comment: Tried but 0 luck :( Ty for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0):

God I finally resolved this, Instead of using the standard cell elements I've added a UIImageView and a UILabel to the cell in order to create a custom cell, then in order to show the image correctly I've added on the `LayoutSubviews` method `cellImg.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;`